# How to use either one of two interfaces in another Typescript interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm not sure how to describe this as I'm learning Typescript.

The issue I'm facing is as follows. There are two interfaces in the application. One for blog posts and one for event posts:

```
type Category = "Foo" | "Bar";

// 1
export interface PostBlog {
  title: string;
  author: string;
  categories: Array<Category>;
}

// 2
export interface PostEvent {
  title: string;
  date: Date;
}
```

Now the data that get's passed through to the components looks like this:

```
import Blogs from "./Blogs";
import Events from "./Events";

const blogPosts = [{ document: { data: { title: "Blogpost title", author: "John Doe" } }, slug: "./blogpost-title" }];
const eventPosts = [{ document: { data: { title: "Event title", date: "01-01-2020" }}, slug: "./event-title" }];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Blogs posts={blogPosts} />
      <Events posts={eventPosts} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then in the component:

```
import * as React from "react";

import { Data } from "../shared.types";

interface BlogPosts {
  posts: Data[];
}

const Blogs: React.FC<BlogPosts> = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {posts.map(({ document: { data } }) => (
        <li>
          Title: {data.title}
          Author: {data.author} // produces the error
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Blogs;
```

So an attempt is:

```
export interface Data {
  document: {
    data: PostBlog | PostEvent; // use it here
    isEmpty?: boolean;
    excerpt?: string;
  };
  slug: string;
}
```

However, Typescript notifies that that isn't allowed since they have properties which aren't in common:

```js
Property 'author' does not exist on type 'PostBlog | PostEvent'.
  Property 'author' does not exist on type 'PostEvent'.ts(2339)
```

[image: Example of the issue]

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-field-o60ry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a `BlogData` and an `EventData` interface in a generic `Data`:

```
// shared.types.ts
export interface BlogData {
  title: string;
  author: string;
}

export interface EventData {
  title: string;
  date: string;
}

export interface Data<T> {
  document: {
    data: T;
    isEmpty?: boolean;
    excerpt?: string;
  };
  slug: string;
}


// Blogs.tsx
import { Data, BlogData } from "../shared.types";

interface BlogPosts {
  posts: Data<BlogData>[];
}

// Events.tsx
import { Data, EventData } from "../shared.types";

interface EventPosts {
  posts: Data<EventData>[];
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-euler-573vq)

For more information on generics, see [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200309055052/https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)).