# Apply interface conditionally on React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to apply a `props` `interface` conditionally on a React component?

This is a basic representation of what I am trying to achieve:

```
interface ButtonProps extends ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'button'> {
  size?: ...
}

interface AnchorProps extends ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'a'> {
  color?: ...
}

const Button: FC<ButtonProps | AnchorProps> = ({href, type}) => {
  return href ? <a href={href}>{children}</a> : <button type={type}>{children}</button>
}
```

Is there a way to prevent applying of conflicting props, or applying the props conditionally ? For example if I pass `href` prop, then only props from the `AnchorProps` `interface` will be valid:

```
<Button href="/">LINK BUTTON</Button> // only AnchorProps will be valid
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630750/react-typescript-component-with-two-different-prop-interfaces check this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60594968/how-to-use-either-one-of-two-interfaces-in-another-typescript-interface and this